# How to properly format body for post request?

Tags: php, jquery, json, rest, post

I'm using a firefox pluing called restclient to simulate a post request.  It doesnt' seem to be picking up any post data, but not sure if I'm formatting it properly.

using header: Content-Type: application/json
and body: {"id":1234}

but not go, it's not picking up the id parameter in my php, is there some special formatting I need to set?

Comment: seems correct. Problem is probably in how you are using this plugin

Comment: well i'm doing a print_r($_POST) in my php code and it's coming up empty.  I've also set the method to "POST" in case anyone is wondering.

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post/8893792#8893792

Answer (score 6, accepted):

okay, got it working, here is what is needed

two content types:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and then set your params like so in body:

```
param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: This might work, but is not really correct. Your content can't have several types. It's just one type which in this case is `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. JSON looks something like `{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}`, and if you had that you would have to set the header to `Content-Type: application/json`. Appearently, now your server simply picks the last header. But this example should also work if you omit the misleading one, since it is not JSON.

Comment: So, when working with url-encoded key-value pairs like `param1=value1&param2=value2`, the correct Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and you can access it through the `$_POST`-array on the server side. If you have JSON data like `{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}`, set the content-type to `application/json` and you can turn the data into an array on the server side with `$data_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`

Answer (score 4):

PHP will not parse a JSON body automatically into the `$_POST` superglobal. That only happens with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` POST bodies. That said, you *can* parse the body yourself — you can access the raw POST body via the [`php://input` pseudo-stream](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Comment: ok, i'ave added Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded, still no go, am I missing something else?  I just want to simulate a POST request.

Comment: Yes. Your actual body content is JSON, it is not enough to just lie the server about what you're sending. You either have to actually encode the body in [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application/x-www-form-urlencoded#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type), or you need to handle the JSON explicitly on the backend.