# jQuery POST response OK, but PHP script doesn't get POST?

Tags: php, jquery, post

I am posting to a php script via jQuery:

```
$.post('http://*****.php', {'clicked':'true'}, 'json');
```

Looking at the post data, it responds with:

```
Request URL:http://*****.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
```

The Form Data in the headers looks like:

```
clicked:true
```

When I attempt to retrieve the POST data on my PHP script via:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

I get an empty array:

```
array(0) { }
```

However, when playing around with the command line, I can successfully view the post data from the response when I do:

```
wget --post-data 'clicked=true' http://****.php
```

The successful response with wget is:

```
array(1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

I have been unable to figure it out... and it's not my HTACCESS file. Also, GET requests work just fine. I'm assuming my jQuery POST is wrong, but don't know what it could be - it comes directly from the jQuery docs.

Comment: at what point are you trying to do the var dump?

Comment: Have you looked inside `php://input`?

Comment: The var dump is at the very top of the script. How do I look in the `php://input`?

Comment: Some have told me to restart the machine... but that is a last resort, as there are some business applications running on it that can't go down right now.

Comment: I bet you $50 that restarting the web server won't fix this problem.

Comment: how are you checking the var_dump? you have no callback on your .post() I'm not sure where you're expecting it to output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When POST data is sent as a JSON string, `$_POST` won't display the data. To access it, you must use `php://input`.

```
$phpinput = file_get_contents("php://input");
if(!$phpinput) {
  //No data was sent
}
else {
  //Do something with yo data
}
```

For the technical details of this, [check out this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post/8893792#8893792) contributed in one of the comments below.

Comment: [This related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8893792/122353) may explain why it works. It looks like jQuery is sending the data not normalized into a querystring, but rather as a JSON string. PHP can't understand this, so it does not get parsed into `$_POST`.

Comment: This seems to be the issue. Thanks.

Comment: After some exploration, it seems as though a previous co-worker messed with the jQuery source code (Don't know why...) and caused the issue. After retrieving jQuery directly from Google CDN, the issue is resolved. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use raw $.ajax instead

`$.ajax({`

url : 'http://*****.php',
  data : {'clicked':'true'},
  dataType : 'json',
  method : 'post'

});