# parse a spaced-string in php

Tags: php, string-parsing

guys i use Parse Post to receive my username and password But when my username included with Space its not work.
my question is How can I parse a spaced-string in my php code?

```
<?php
function ParsePost( )
{
    $username = '';
    $password = '';

    $post = file_get_contents( "php://input" );

    $post = str_replace( "&", " ", $post );

    sscanf( $post, "%s  %s", $username, $password );

    return array( 'user' => $username,
              'pass' => $password
                );
}

?>
```

Comment: I have a question my self: If the data is being posted to you, why not access them through $_POST ??? If it is not beign posted, then why name the variable $post, which will confuse other people or you after a few weeks ?

Comment: I sent username and password with c++ programing (&CURL)...

Comment: @gkalpak https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add:

```
$post = str_replace( " ", "_", $post );
```

Before:

```
$post = str_replace( "&", " ", $post );
```

The username will result with `_`s so you may want to convert them back to spaces before the return:

```
$username = str_replace( "_", " ", $username);
```

This will replace `_` with a space as well.

The best way to do this is actually using an explode.

```
list($username, $password) = explode('$', $post);
```

Comment: Careful, though, when the username contains a `_` then it is converted to " " :)

Comment: So what problem with that?

Comment: Replacing characters should be avoided for reasons like those specified by @ExpertSystem

Comment: @Ramin It is a problem. You should actually use an unsupported character instead of `_`, like `\x1E`.

Comment: what u think i use Alt+0160 ?

Comment: thank but sorry for my stupidly qus :| where i put this code so there is no need _ ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `sscanf( $post, "%s&%s", $username, $password );`

OR

Use following style code:

```
function ParsePost( )
{

    //$post = "Username&Password";

    $post = file_get_contents( "php://input" );

    $pieces = explode('&', $post);

    return array( 'user' => $pieces[0],
              'pass' => $pieces[1]
                );
}
```