# Reading json input in php

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, rest

`php://input` is working properly in localhost. But in server it returns empty.
Input( request ) to my site is a `json`(*REST - application/json type*), so `$_POST` didn't work ( please read [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post) ) .

> $_POST works with key-value pair type inputs like form-data or x-www-urlencoded
>
> **key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3**

I'm using `application/json` as input (in **REST**).

> Like {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}

This can't be handled using `$_POST`. But using `php://input` can help to read that data.

My code

```
class Webservice_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public $json_input_data;
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->json_input_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),TRUE);
    }
    public function json_input($label){
        if(isset($this->json_input_data[$label])) return $this->json_input_data[$label];
        else return NULL;
    }
}
```

*Above code is works fine in another webserver also, But not in the current one. :(*

I think my web server deny access to `php://input`.

> **Is there is any other methods to read json input in php ?**

Comment: first things to check, is the php versions the same, and if `allow_fopen_url` is set

Comment: Try `var_dump($this->json_input_data )` in `__construct()`

Comment: @RohanKumar -> it prints "NULL" in server i hosted. Prints "array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "79"
  ["t"]=>
  string(5) "22_00"
}" in localhost.

Comment: @DevZer0 PHP version is 5.3 and it supports. I didn't find an option to access php.ini file in my control panel ( it's a shared server ). Is there any method to test that ? Plz help..

Answer (score 4):

> php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data
>   from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable
>   to use php://input instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not
>   depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where
>   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated by default, it is a potentially
>   less memory intensive alternative to activating
>   always_populate_raw_post_data. **php://input** is not available with
>   **enctype="multipart/form-data"**.

See [wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

Try this too,

```
....
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    if(isset($_POST))
    {
       var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
       $this->json_input_data=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),TRUE);
    }
    else echo 'Not Post';
  }
....
```

**Also** check for `allow_url_fopen`.

Comment: I saw the wrappers, and also the input isn't enctype="multipart/form-data". It works fine in localhost, but the web server i used to host returns null while i using php://input. May be it denay access to that. I want to know is it possible to do in any other methods ???

Comment: it gives "NULL" in server i hosted. Prints "array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "79" ["t"]=> string(5) "22_00" }" in localhost. It's mentioned in comments of the question. I think 'php://input' is not accessible in that web server.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but it might help others:

**Careful with single quotes inside your json**

From the PHP documentation about json_decode:

```
the name and value must be enclosed in double quotes
single quotes are not valid 

$bad_json = "{ 'bar': 'baz' }";
json_decode($bad_json); // null
```