# Angular Js $httpParamSerializer and jQuery $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I am working on an Angular.js app and I have to send a POST request to a PHP server. The data I am sending is object of objects.

Something like:

```
var data = {
    "serviceID": "0001",
    "interpreterDetails": {
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Wilson",
        "password": "Peter",
        "rePassword": "Peter",
        "address": "alex",
        "mobPhone": "01224747748",
        "homePhone": "3910009",
        "mail": "peter@server.domain",
        "fax": "556",
        "hourlyRate": "10",
        "OperatingSys": "android",
        "token": "432132",
        "dialectId": "1"
    }
}
```

when I send this object using angular

```
$http({
     url: "http://localhost/saveInterpreter.php",
     method: "POST",
     data: $httpParamSerializer(data),
     headers : {
       "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;"
     }
 })
```

and the code in the server returns

```
object(stdClass)#3 (9) {  
["interpreterDetails"]=>
 string(262) " {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Wilson","password":"Peter","rePassword":"Peter","address":"alex","mobPhone":"01224747748","homePhone":"3910009","mail":"peter@server.domain","fax":"556","hourlyRate":"10","OperatingSys":"android","token":"432132","dialectId":"1"}"
["serviceID"]=>
string(4) "0001"
}
```

but the expected return is

```
object(stdClass)#3 (8) {
["serviceID"]=>
string(4) "0001"
["interpreterDetails"]=>
object(stdClass)#4 (13) {
["firstName"]=>
string(5) "zxczc"
["lastName"]=>
string(4) "zxcz"
["password"]=>
string(4) "1234"
["rePassword"]=>
string(4) "1234"
["address"]=>
string(4) "sada"
["mobPhone"]=>
string(4) "4532"
["homePhone"]=>
string(4) "1351"
["mail"]=>
string(11) "asd@sdsd.sd"
["fax"]=>
string(6) "123513"
["hourlyRate"]=>
string(2) "26"
["OperatingSys"]=>
string(0) ""
["token"]=>
string(0) ""
["dialectId"]=>
string(1) "1"
 }
}
```

The problem is that the object inside (interpreterDetails) the outer object (data) is being returned as a string and not an object.

any help with that

NOTE : when I use jQuery it returns the expected results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that it is being JSON stringified.

You can use `json_decode()` to to provide expected results

```
$_POST['interpreterDetails'] = json_decode( $_POST['interpreterDetails'] );
```

Process would be simpler by using `$http` default of data sent as `application/json` and using `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))` to access the data in php.

---

**EDIT**: If you insist on  form encoded data try using

```
data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data)
```

I've never used it but it may be recursive to replicate the same as jQuery as suggested by it's name

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't use:

```
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;"
```

It'd be a better idea to work with:

```
"Content-Type": "application/json"
```

Angular will transform objects in `data` into JSON:

> Angular provides the following default transformations:
>
> Request transformations (`$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest` and `$http.defaults.transformRequest`):
>
> If the `data` property of the request configuration object contains an object, serialize it into JSON format.

So, all you got to do is pass the object as it is and it will be converted to JSON automatically by you.

```
data : data
```

If you use `application/json` then you won't be able to pick it up through `$_POST` but you can do so through **php://input**, more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371751/reading-json-input-in-php).

If you insist on using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
data : $httpParamSerializer({ jsonData : JSON.stringify(data) })
```

And then you'll just need to parse the string normally from PHP (it  populates `$_POST['jsonData']`)

Answer (score 0):

See @MinusFour 's (better) answer

I think the issue is with [httpParamSerializer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer)

httpParamSerializer is used primarily (?) to convert JSON data into a URL param format when sending GET requests

Example) `{query: 'test'}` to `?query=test`

The POST request and `data: httpParamSerializer(data)` is sending the data in the body of the request anyway so you don't have any special need to format the data as http parameters.

As @charlietfl mentioned, it is stringifying your inner object and making it into a string rather than respecting the actual object format.

You can either parse the JSON (as charlie mentioned) or try removing the $httpParamSerializer.

```
{
    ...
    data: data,
    ...
}
```