# How to handle json data, which I send via ajax request, in php script?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I am sending some json data with ajax:

```
function send() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/index.php?action=setShopOrdersGoods&order_id='+orderId,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#target').html(data.msg);
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(goods)
    });
}
```

There are no problems with it. Firebug console screen:

[image]

Soajax request is sending okay. Now I need to handle it.

How I can do this?

```
echo __FILE__;
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

This code shows nothing. Looks like there are no data send via post. Firebug response tab of sent ajax request:

[image]

How I can handle json data in php file then?

Comment: how do you evaluate that your php shows nothing? If you just open the path to it it surely will show nothing since it needs a `post` request for that. Are you aware of that? You browser tools can show you the servers response for whem you send data via ajax. Try that.

Comment: @DS9 If dumping `$_POST` shows nothing, it is very unlikely that `$_POST['items']` will show something right?

Comment: I updated my question - added response - result of php code above.

Comment: @Sharikov. Is your PHP code in index.php? Maybe at the top?

Comment: your response tab shows ajax.php but you use index.php in your json. this doesn't seem right

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles No. It is in `/modules/ajax.php` file. This file is included only it somebody doing ajax request.

Comment: Your approach to get data from $_POST is correct (*given you send data via post*) and not the problem here. The error seems to be somewhere else. It is dubious that you send to index.php and get results in your firefox tab by ajax.php.

Comment: [How I handle ajax request in index.php?](http://i.gyazo.com/992457e83f34bcc4ce19b1fb82899522.png)

Comment: You are calling index.php with your AJAX call. Put `var_dump()` in your index.php page, or change your ajax to point to ajax.php

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles As you see in my 2nd screen _correct_ file giving result.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav, what file is your jQuery ajax call in?

Comment: @bloody `index.php`. In `index.php` I have section, which detects ajax request and load `/modules/ajax.php` file, as I said below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json data does not receive in post.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post = json_decode($json, TRUE);

echo __FILE__;
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($post);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

Comment: Worked. What is `php://input`?

Comment: `php://input`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post Cool.

Comment: json data is saved into tmp, which is get through it

Comment: Wow. I did not know that. How did i not know that? Frameworks! They take all the work out of your hands and leave you clueless :-D

Comment: @AndreschSerj I am not using framework. Simple logic. The question was not about how I handle ajax request etc. I asked why I am getting nothing when `var_dump($_POST)` and author of this answer helped me.