# Parsing raw query input, or query string to obtain http post and get vars. What benefit?

Tags: php, slim

For example SLim Framework, if I'm not mistaken, not used $_POST and $_GET predefined vars to getting this values. Instead, the query string or php://input is parsed. What the benefit of this way?

upd.
Probably, this way for convenient getting PUT, PATCH, DELETE vars from php://input

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP "php://input" vs $\_POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)