# PHP not receiving data from XMLhttprequest

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

Hi I am sending data to a php script like so:

```
function ajax(url,data,success) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", url);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(object) {
        if(request.readyState === 3) {
            success(request);
        }
    };
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
    request.send(data);
}
```

The data being sent is a stringifyed javascript object.  The post definitely works and the object shows in the payload section in chromes dev tools.  But the php script I am sending to request object is empty.  The php script's content type is set to json.

Comment: Can you add your php code?

Comment: It's just a `var_dump($_REQUEST);` which is showing empty.

Comment: If you look in your browser console, can you see the data you're trying to send in POST?

Comment: Is `var_dump( $_POST );` empty as well?

Comment: @unixarmy of course, REQUEST contains POSTS

Comment: @unixarmy of course, request contains post variables.

Comment: @frankastin, you are not completely right. It might be issue caused by poorly configured PHP. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're experiencing quite a well-known issue (some info here: [PHP "php://input" vs $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post))

You should be able to access the data with file_get_contents('php://input')

Comment: Cheers, that did it.  I presume jQuery's ajax converts it across to url-form vars before sending.

Comment: You're welcome. It's quite a common issue - I've had the same problem before and hence how I was able to guess that's what you were having! :D