# Error reciving json at server side using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to send json with ajax to php file for that I have tried below code

1. Using jquery

   ```
   var dummyData = {'bob': 'foo', 'paul': 'dog'};
   var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
           url: "json_handler.php",
           type: "POST",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: JSON.stringify(dummyData ),
           dataType: "json"
       });
       ajaxRequest.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           console.log(response + textStatus + jqXHR);
           alert('sd');
       });

       ajaxRequest.fail(function (e) {
           console.log(e);

       });
   ```

And i am just doing `var_dump($_REQUEST)` at `json_handler.php` and ajax request is keep failing and get nothing in response text

When i tried

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($json);
```

I got the json but ajax request is still failing.

I have also tried to do this javascript and my code is below

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = stateHandler;
httpRequest.open("POST", "json_handler.php", true);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
httpRequest.send( JSON.stringify(dummyData ));
```

Here is my console log

> [image]

Comment: I see status 200 on the requests.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i also see the 200 but why request with jquery is failing and i am not getting alert from the done method also why i have to `file_get_contents('php://input');` to get json

Comment: Do you get an error if the php file is blank?

Comment: no i am not getting any error

Comment: What is your php file trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See because your ajax is having `dataType: "json"` so it is expecting the response in `json` format which is like `{key:value} or [{k:v}, {k:v}, ....]` and you are not `echo`ing any json structure so this is where your ajax is failing.

Seems to me you have to write it this way:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: thanks its working fine now , but why i have to use file_get_contents rather than just $_REQUEST

Comment: That is because you have changed the headers in the ajax code `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` if you do this then you have to use `file_get_contents` because php natively support `formurlencoded` query strings. [This will help you understanding it.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8893792/1059101)

Comment: so you mean if i dont use  `application/json;`  header and as i am stringfy json it should work

Comment: if you remove `application/json` then you don't have to strigify either ajax just needs an object to be passed `data:{k:v}` would be enough.

Comment: i have tried  `$.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(serData),
            });` now i  am not getting data at server but when i get data by `file_get_contents` its working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87754/discussion-between-richerd-fuld-and-jai).

Comment: @Richerdfuld and at PHP end you need to decode it before `json_decode`.

Answer (score 0):

Your request seems good, but why do you stringify your JSON?

You can post payload data:

```
data: dummyData
```

To debug and test your json post, you can use extensions as Postman or Advanced Rest Client.

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop