# Fetching JSON object out of HTTP request

Tags: php, json, api, post, request

Folks I think I may miss a dead simple thing but I just have no idea where to look for it.

So I'm trying to implement [block.io](https://block.io/docs/notifications/php) API to accept bitcoin payments on a website built on PHP. Now the Docs say that all notification events will use JSON objects pushed to my server through POST requests. So I decided to make a test BTC payment and log all requests on a specified URL to my DB. And here what I gen on dumping `getallheaders()`

```
{
["Content-Type"]=>
string(16) "application/json"
["User-Agent"]=>
string(12) "Block.io/0.1"
["Accept"]=>
string(10) "text/plain"
["Authorization"]=>
string(10) "Basic Og=="
["Connection"]=>
string(5) "close"
["Host"]=>
string(17) "site.com"
["Content-Length"]=>
string(3) "462" }
```

But dumping `$_POST` gives me an empty array. Dumping `$_SERVER` and `$_GET` gives nothing useful either.
So my question is how can I find the JSON string declared in Content-Type?

Any suggestion would be helpful!
Thanks!

Comment: no, i don't think i should, because they push notification to me on the BTC transaction completion

Comment: right, ok - I see now looking at the docs what is going on ~ sorry for the confusion.

Comment: it's ok, thanks for the feedback anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Content-Type is `application/json` (not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)
`$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');`

EDIT: excellent explanation at [PHP "php://input" vs $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)

Comment: But could you please explain in plain words, why should I perform file_get_contents('php://input')? Because I'm pretty sure there are other noob coders like me out there :)

Comment: Sure. 
There is an excellent explanation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post