# How do I get data from Webhook to store in a database?

Tags: php, json, post, sendgrid, webhooks

I am working with a Webhook based of of SendGrid's API v3. The Webhook is completely set up with an endpoint that SendGrid posts to, but I need to be able to receive that parsed data and store it in a database using PHP, but do not know how to do that.

I have worked with APIs before where I initiate the retrieval or POST of data, but when the API server is the one POSTing, how do I catch the data being parsed through the Webhook endpoint? I have some simple thus far, but am really unclear of how to tackle this:

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('https://example.com/webhook.php');
$json_decoded = json_decode($json, true);
$var_dump(json_decoded);

?>
```

I have tried sending multiple emails to the host, but every time I make this call I return `NULL`.

Comment: try using Guzzle in order to do the http request

Comment: Is that a service to debug webhooks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the code from [this example](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/Webhook_Examples/php.html#-Event-Webhook). This will give you the raw HTTP request body bytes to decode.

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$events = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($events as $event) {
  // Here, you now have each event and can process them how you like
  process_event($event);
}
?>
```

More info on [`php://input`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)

Comment: Where would I call the url that SendGrid is POSTing to?

Comment: You don't. that code goes into the file that your webhook URL points to... you then need to have that page hosted and available. You are creating a server to respond to requests. This post might help: https://sendgrid.com/blog/whats-webhook/