# Getting values sent using post method in controller in magento 2 api

Tags: php, api, magento2

I can not get values sent from post method, using http request.

I am getting values using get method, but I need to get it using post method.

I am not using any view, I want to call http url, and send some data in my controller using post method.

This is how my controller looks like,

```
namespace Spaarg\eMenuApi\Controller\Index;

class Products extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context)
    {
      return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {   
      //$token = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
      $token = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    }
}
```

I am new to magento 2, and I don't understand what is the problem.
It will be great if someone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably has to do with the `Content-type` of the http request, where Magento only understands Json and Xml (this is [explained here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/103703/24432)). If you're using a different `Content-type` in the request or your data doesn't match the type declared in the header, then `getPost()` will not work.

As a fallback, you can always get all the POST data by using the following way:

```
public function execute()
{   
    $postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
}
```

Keep in mind that this will get the raw string, so you will likely need to process it accordingly before using it (for example with `json_decode()` or something like that).

For more information about this, check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8893574/1446479).