# how i can get response from json array using post method in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, post, content-type

I am facing error while getting response from JSON array.
here is PHP code I try this code.

```
var_dump($_POST);die;
```

empty

```
$data = (array) json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, true);
var_dump($data);
```

empty

```
$arJson =(array) json_decode( $_POST, true );
var_dump($arJson);
```

this one also empty here is postman results.

[image]
[image]

Comment: when `var_dump($_POST);` is empty it means no data in post. check if your request is coming to your server or not . just to check try `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: try echo instead var_dump

Comment: @ChetanAmeta `echo will display Array as string text` since `$_POST` is an array.he can use `print_r` instead.

Comment: 'path_gen' => string 'api/sync_messages/'

Comment: Which is not you data.

Comment: bro its api .
and other developer send  me JSON array .

Comment: read this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post

Comment: @Chetan Ameta result of echo is simple Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
`$postData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));`

If you simply POST a good old HTML form, the request looks something like this:

```
POST /page.php HTTP/1.1

key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3
```

But if you are working with Ajax a lot, this probaby also includes exchanging more complex data with types (string, int, bool) and structures (arrays, objects), so in most cases JSON is the best choice. But a request with a JSON-payload would look something like this:

```
POST /page.php HTTP/1.1

{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}
```

The content would now be application/json (or at least none of the above mentioned), so PHP's $_POST-wrapper doesn't know how to handle that (yet).

The data is still there, you just can't access it through the wrapper. So you need to fetch it yourself in raw format with `file_get_contents('php://input')` (as long as it's not `multipart/form-data-encoded`).

Comment: bro its api . how can store $_post array in json file

Comment: We are not storing the data in json file. The data sent in POST body as input stream because the content type in this case is in application/json.

Answer (score 2):

If your whole POST body contains the JSON, you can get it using thid piece of code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: bro its api .
how can store $_post array in json file

Comment: If I understood yor comment correctly, you want to put the JSON encoded POST data into a file: `file_put_contents('/path/to/file.json', $_POST)`

Answer (score 1):

You can get value like this:

```
$str = file_get_content("php://input");
$data = json_decode($str,true);
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: bro its api . how can store $_post array in json file