# Get variables from a POST Method without HTML form

Tags: javascript, php

I want to pass javascript variables (without form) to php, so php can write them in a textfile on the server-side. For this, I'm using this jQuery line:

```
$.post( "http://localhost/main.php", data);
```

Here is the php:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
echo $data;

$file = "test.txt"
$handle = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);
```

I think the problem could be the 'data' tag, when I try to access the information in php, but I don't know what should I put there since all the examples that I found was associated with html forms.

The other thing tho', which I don't really understand is: I do this whole thing on a button-click, so if I click the button, it posts to the php, but does that actually run the above php code, and writes in the text file or am I missing something?

*btw, I use WAMP for PHP, but I don't think it matters.

Comment: how does the `data` object look like?

Comment: Why are you not using Ajax?

Comment: @SatishGupta They are using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) ...

Comment: var data = {
    hours: 0,
    mins: 0,
    secs: 0,
    tenths: 0
};
but it is incremented before I pass it.

on var_dump($_POST) gives back:
array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: You should read `$_POST('hours')` etc ...

Comment: I'm not trying to send the actual time, but an arbitrary one. so its just a simple object with 4 properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Semi-Copying my answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677423/sending-object-data-from-ajax-to-php/42677898#42677898)

PHP is kind of interesting in that it doesn't pull from $_POST like other forms when Ajax is involved. You actually will need to read the input from php://input

Here is a tiny example

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$response = json_decode($data, true ); // True converts to array; blank converts to object

$emailAddr = $response["hour"];
```

Hopefully you can apply that successfully.

While debugging this I would highly recommend using Chrome's Developer mode with the 'network' tab. Find your ajax call near the bottom and you can view exact header info.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I send the POST request, I can console out this on the client-side: 
Time saved on the server!{"hours":"00","mins":"00","secs":"01","tenths":"2"}.
Then the PHP gets the request, as I can see it in the headers, and it also has 200 status code. Then I try to var-dump it, and it says:
C:\wamp64\www\phpsandbox\timePlusPlus\main.php:4:string '' (length=0).
The code looks like this:
$data = file_get_contents("php://input"); var_dump($data);
Do you have any idea, why this happening? Note, that on client-side it says POST, but on the server it says it's a GET.

Comment: @hotigeftas if Php is reading it as empty it's likely the request isn't coming through properly, I would watch the network tab as you submit this and see how the headers look, and ensure the data object is passing properly.

Answer (score 1):

Post data is submitted in key/value pairs. For your payload that's:

`hours => 0, mins => 0, secs => 0, tenths => 0`

After the POST request PHP has this data inside of the $_POST associative array.
To access `hours` for example you'd write `$hours = $_POST["hours"]`. 
If you want to write the data to the text file you now need to tell PHP what the file should look like:

```
<?php
$hours = $_POST["hours"],
$mins = $_POST["mins"]
.
.
.

$fileDataToWrite = "Hours: ".$hours." Minutes: ".$mins // and so on
```

This variable can now be passed to the fwrite function as the second parameter:

```
$file = "test.txt"
$handle = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($handle, $fileDataToWrite);
fclose($handle);
```

The resulting file would then look like this:

```
Hours: 0 Minutes: 0
```

You can choose how you want the file to look like, or if you for example want it to be in JSON format by simply changing how you build the `$fileDataToWrite` variable.

In your JS code you should add a callback for when the PHP has ran on the server side:

```
$.post("http://localhost/main.php", data, 
    response => console.log("Time saved on the server!"));
```

Comment: The php page keeps throwing "unidentified index: hours" to this line: $hours = $_POST["hours"];
and for the others as well. Do you have a guess why is it happening?

Comment: could you try implementing @JohnPavek's answer?