# PHP Curl Send JSON Data

Tags: php, json, curl

I am following this tutorial:
https://lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl

what I am trying to do is POST JSON Data through CURL

```
$url = "http://localhost/test/test1.php";  
$data = array("name" => "Hagrid", "age" => "36");

$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                                                     
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Content-type: application/json", "Content-Length: " . strlen($data_string)));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

when I POST plain text data , I am able to receive that, but when I try through JSON , I am not able to receive that.

Here is my test1.php

```
test1.php

print_r($_POST);
print_r($_POST);
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This could be related: [**PHP “php://input” vs $_POST**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post).

Comment: `die(curl_error());` and tell us what that says

Comment: @delboy1978uk no error, it does send a request to a page, but test1.php is not accepting $_POST when I try to send json string.

Comment: Wait, both files are on the same server? Why do an HTTP request? Why not just require in test1.php and use `$result` there?

Answer (score 2):

When you `POST JSON Data` through `cURL`, you have to use `php://input`. You can use it like:

```
// get the raw POST data
$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");

// this returns null if not valid json
return json_decode($rawData, true);  // will return array
```

> `php://input` is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data
>   from the request body

The PHP superglobal `$_POST`, only is supposed to wrap data that is either

- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (standard content type for simple form-posts) or
- `multipart/form-data-encoded` (mostly used for file uploads)

The content would now be `application/json` (or at least none of the above mentioned), so PHP's `$_POST` -wrapper doesn't know how to handle that (yet).

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

Answer (score 2):

JSON data does not come through in $_POST. You need to use `file_get_contents('php://input');`

You will also need to json_decode it.

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

var_dump($json);
```