# JQUERY AJAX $_POST is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two files, a javascript file, and a PHP file.

In the JS file, i'm running a POST request.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost/tracker/functions.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
        name: "John Doe",
        age: "19"
    },
    success: function (obj, textstatus) {
        console.log(textstatus);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr, status, error);
    }
});
```

and I'm simply print $_POST in the php file

```
<?php
   print_r($_POST);
?>
```

which just prints an empty array

Comment: Have you check to see if PHP is set to automatically parse POST input?

Comment: There is a form to post or not?

Comment: Are you running a web server on your local computer? Use your browser tools to see what is being sent.

Comment: What happened if you `console.log(obj);`? You are logging the status and not the result.

Comment: @ColinCline not a form

Comment: @JasonK yep.. browser tools show the data in the POST request

Comment: @Eddie it logs the POST data successfully

Comment: @bassxzero did not

Comment: change `dataType: json`

Comment: @PrateikDarji that makes no sense when what is being returned isn't json

Comment: Are you using some sort of framework that overrides and empties globals like `$_POST`? There is no reason what is shown shouldn't work assuming php is actually being compiled and path is correct

Comment: @charlietfl im not.. this is what baffles me

Comment: Check the datatype attribute in your browser's console. As per the [`$_POST` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php): "An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method **when using *application/x-www-form-urlencoded***" (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get JSON data from my PHP script I usually do

```
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
```

So maybe you can do in your php file

```
<?php
  print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'));
?>
```

Cf [PHP "php://input" vs $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)