# POST data being received but not in as a form variable or file

Tags: php, post

I'm using a u-blox gsm module (potentially irrelevant) to send POST commands to a server. I'm using `http:/httpbin.org`(`/post`) to echo back the POST information that Im sending. The result is

```
...

"args": {},
"data": "Hello World",
"files": {},
"form": {},

...
```

Thus suggesting that it's just data being received and not a file or parts of a form.

I've tried to use

```
<?php

  echo "THIS IS THE SERVER RESPONSE:\n\n";
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    print_r($_POST);
  }
?>
```

but got an empty array back

```
THIS IS THE SERVER RESPONSE:

Array
(
)
```

What is the correct PHP command to use to echo the "data" back to the user?

Note: obviously in a real situation you wouldn't echo arbitrary data back to the user, that isn't the point here.

Comment: try to `var_dump` this: `file_get_contents("php://input")`.

Comment: Yes, `$_POST` could be empty provided the content type isn't `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data-encoded`

Comment: @FirstOne `var_dump` returns `string(11) "Hello World"` - which is great! Is this common practice or are there better ways of integrating this?

Comment: It's mentioned in @Kisaragi's comment, but read this: [PHP “php://input” vs $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post).

Comment: Basically, PHP will only parse data into `$_POST` when said header is passed.