# input->post and $_POST are empty in CodeIgniter API calling from Angular 4, what is the right way to make a post request in angular 4

Tags: php, angular, codeigniter, post

This is the first time I'm making a post method request from Angular to CodeIgniter rest API.

```
postUsertask(Userid,TaskName)
  {
    let body ={
      userid:Userid, taskname:TaskName
    };  
    console.log(body);
    return this.http.post("http://localhost/ci-abc/api/add_task",JSON.stringify(body) )
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

API method in codeigniter:

```
function add_task_post()
{
    $obj=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    $taskname = $obj->taskname;
    $userid = $obj->userid;
    if (!$taskname || !$userid) {
        $this->response("Enter taskname and userid to add", 400);
    } else

        $result = $this->todo_model->add_task($taskname, $userid);

    if ($result === 0) {
        $this->response("Task could not be added. Try again.", 404);
    } else {
        $this->response("success", 200);
    }
}
```

Had to include to access the data

> $obj=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

Because the $this->input->post and $_POST were empty and the data recieved from angular was an object so had to be accessed with -> notation. I am curious that this is not the right and ethical way to do this. Also when I didn't put JSON.stringify it gave me Cross Origin Request blocked error so that's why I put it. How should I make POST and PUT request in angular4 to rest API in CodeIgniter?

How do I get rid of CORS error which doesn't let me call the API method, if I can get rid of CORS error then I could also remove `JSON.stringify` which will send the data as it is and I believe the data should be accessed via `input->post` or `$_POST`.

EDIT 2:
These sort of errors while making POST PUT and DELETE API call.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://localhost/ci-abc/api/del_task?taskid=34.
>   (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP "php://input" vs $\_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)

Comment: I don't know how to solve it in angular.

Comment: file_get_contents("php://input")  you should try with this

Comment: I am already using that @MayankVadiya why cant I use input->post() why is it empty is it because of JSON.stringify i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT (Perfect Solution):**

Found out that the formdata object approach was deprecated so I just included a header in options and included in the API call http.post method which works fine and is much better solution.

```
constructor(public http:Http) { 
let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });}

createUser(userName)
  {
    let body = { username:userName};
    return this.http.post("http://localhost/ci-abc/api/create_user",body,this.options)
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

**Deprecated approach (Works but deprecated/not usual practice):**

Took few hours but found the solution, I created body as a new formdata object, appended parameters to it as key and their values and it worked fine now I am retrieving through $this->input->post.

```
  let body = new FormData;
    body.append('userid', Userid);
    body.append('taskname', TaskName);
    console.log(body);
    return this.http.post("http://localhost/ci-abc/api/add_task",body)
    .map(res => res.json());
```

Using these headers in the constructor of my codeigniters API controller

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
```

API method:

```
 function add_task_post()
    {
        $userid = $this->input->post('userid');
        $taskname = $this->input->post('taskname');

        if (!$taskname || !$userid) {
            $this->response("Enter taskname and userid to add", 400);
        } else
            $result = $this->todo_model->add_task($taskname, $userid);
        if ($result === 0) {
            $this->response("Task could not be added. Try again.", 404);
        } else {
            $this->response("success", 200);
        }
    }
```