# Angular 5/PHP : Http failure during parsing for [URL]

Tags: php, angular

**Context:**

Newbie here. I'm currently making a project using Angular 5 as front-end and PHP as back-end. I'm just trying to make a post method sending a string as parameter with an Angular Service and using that string as a parameter for my sql query in php.

**Issue :**

I managed without problem to send my string to my service. But then sending it using my post method produce this error :

> ERROR 
>   {…}
>   error: Object { error: SyntaxError, text: "array(1) {\n  [\"{\"name\":\"Rick_Sanchez\"}\"]=>\n  string(0) \"\"\n}\n
> \n
>
> **Notice**:  Undefined index: name in **C:\xampp5.6\htdocs\compte-rendu-app\api\prtcptData\getPrtcptData.php** on line **16**
> \nnull" }
>
> headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map, lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: HttpHeaders/this.lazyInit() }
>
> message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/compte-rendu-app/api/prtcptData/getPrtcptData.php"
>
> name: "HttpErrorResponse"
>
> ok: false
>   status: 200
>
> statusText: "OK"
>
> url: "http://localhost:4200/compte-rendu-app/api/prtcptData/getPrtcptData.php"

So what i understand from it, is that there is an **issue implying the JSON parsing of my parameter.** But i used several ways of sending it and nothing seems to work. Otherwise the issue could be coming from my php. I used almost the same code for a get a method and it worked just fine.

**My files :**

**prtcptData.service.ts :**

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
};

@Injectable()
export class PrtcptDataService {
  urlGet = '/compte-rendu-app/api/prtcptData/getPrtcptData.php';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  /* GET data from the selected name */
  getPrtcptData(name: string): Observable<PrtcptData> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.urlGet,  name, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

**getPrtcptData.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();
    require('./../fonctions.php');

    function formData($data){
        if($data == null) {
            return 'Missing Data';
        }else{
            return $data;
        }
    }

        $post_name = $_POST['name'];
        $bdd = connectDb("Crapo");

        $cmdSQL = "SELECT ipt_id, ipt_organisme, ipt_prenom_nom,
                        ipt_fonction, ipt_mail, ipt_telephone
                   FROM INFOS_PARTCPT
                   WHERE ipt_prenom_nom = :post_name";

        $stmt = $bdd->prepare($cmdSQL);
        $stmt->bindParam(':post_name', $post_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $list = array();
        while($row = $stmt->fetchObject()){
            $retour[] = array(
                'ipt_id' => formData($row->ipt_id),
                'ipt_organisme' => formData($row->ipt_organisme),
                'ipt_prenom_nom' => formData($row->ipt_prenom_nom),
                'ipt_fonction' => formData($row->ipt_fonction),
                'ipt_mail' => formData($row->ipt_mail),
                'ipt_telephone' => formData($row->ipt_telephone)
            );
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        if(empty($retour)) $retour = null;
        echo json_encode($retour);
```

So i think the real question is : what is the right way to do my post method with my current setup ? I've been trying many solutions for several hours but i'm out of them right now. Can someone help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Thank you Cbroe ! I'm checking that.

Comment: It worked ! You and Shushu had the same idea. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

the error is clearly describe the problem,
you don't have 'name' in the POST

change your angular post code to send object and the name in it

```
getPrtcptData(name: string): Observable<PrtcptData> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.urlGet,  {name: name}, httpOptions);
 }
```

Comment: Hi shushu,I've already tried that way and i get the same error. It still doesn't recognized it.

Comment: i see ... you need to get the POST['name'] from the php::input,
or change your post header and remove the content-type json

Comment: you can use this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post

Comment: Thank you i'll dig into that. The issue seems close to mine.

Comment: great ... you can vote up :)

Comment: Yup it worked. Thank you very much !