# JSON from URL returns null

Tags: php, json, postman

I call a PHP file from POSTMAN with this URL: http://localhost/st/user_login.php?surat=DRIVER&sandi=123

In `user_login.php`, I type this to process JSON:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
$email = $obj['surat'];
$password = $obj['sandi'];
```

The problem is, `$email` always returns a null value.
Can somebody tell me where the problem is?

Comment: You are sending GET variables - have you checked `$_GET` ?  Try `print_r($_GET)` and see if you have the data you want

Comment: `file_get_contents('php://input')` does not return JSON because that isn't what you sent to it. You data is in the `$_GET` variables.

Answer (score 0):

When we use `php://input` [PHP "php://input" vs $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)

Try to use `$_GET` or `$_POST`. In your case, clearly, you need to use `$_GET`. But, it's better for security reason we need to use `$_POST`.

For example, using POST man and `php://input`

- Body: raw - JSON(application/json)
- POST

[image]

PHP test script

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);

$result = [];
$result['message'] = 'Success Message';
$result['email'] = $obj['email'];
echo json_encode($result);
```