# PHP file reports success but MySQL database not updated

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, post, pdo

I am trying to send some data from a JavaScript program to a MySQL database using a PHP file (using PDO). I had gotten it to work a few months ago, but I accidentally deleted the file containing the `save_data()` function I use to send the data from the JavaScript file to the PHP file, and I can't get it to work anymore.

Here is my save_data function:

```
function save_data(expData){
    data = JSON.stringify(expData)
    $.post('./saveData.php',data,function(response){
        console.log("Response: "+response);
    })
}
```

And here is my PHP file:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=host;dbname=name;",'admin','p');

$data = json_decode ($_POST['json'], true);

$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `response` (`ip`, `complete_sequence`, `total_wins`, `key_presses`, `run_length`, `subject_condition`, `time_elapsed`, `total_answered`, `total_forfeits`, `total_losses`, `total_missed`, `total_paper`, `total_rock`, `total_scissors`, `total_ties`, `run_test_part_one`, `run_test_part_two`, `run_test_part_three`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")->execute([
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
$data['completeSequence'],
$data['totalWins'],
$data['key_presses'],
$data['runLength'],
implode (", ", $data['SubjectCondition']),
$data['time_elapsed'],
$data['totalAnswered'],
$data['totalForfeits'],
$data['totalLosses'],
$data['totalMissed'],
$data['totalPaper'],
$data['totalRock'],
$data['totalScissors'],
$data['totalTies'],
$data['runsTestPartOne'],
$data['runsTestPartTwo'],
$data['runsTestPartThree']
]);

echo "{'result':'success'}";
```

What I find strange is that the PHP file reports success after `save_data()` runs in the code, but no new rows are added to my Database (it doesn't update).

Also, the PHP file has not been touched since I was last able to successfully update my database, so I'm fairly sure that the problem lies in `save_data()`, but I can't figure out what that is.

I've already looked through already answered questions about issues similar to this, but in all the cases I could find the problem was that a row with a specific entry was not found, so 0 rows were successfully updated. In this case, nothing in the Database is being searched for, I am adding a completely new row, so I can't understand why I would get a success message if the Database is not updated.

I'm very new to web development, so any help I could get with this would be really appreciated!

UPDATE:
I've been asked to show where the data is sent from. The data is sent from an HTML file written using a JavaScript library called JsPsych. The actual program itself is very lengthy but here is the specific part where the relevant data is stored and `save_data()` is called:

```
 //place data in jsPych data structure
    jsPsych.data.addDataToLastTrial({
        totalAnswered: subjectData.answered,
        totalMissed: subjectData.missed,
        totalRock: subjectData.rock,
        totalPaper: subjectData.paper,
        totalScissors: subjectData.scissor,
        completeSequence: full_sequence,
        totalWins: finalscore.wins,
        totalLosses: finalscore.losses,
        totalTies: finalscore.ties,
        totalForfeits: finalscore.forfeits,
        runLength: runLength.toString(),
        runsTestPartOne: partOneRT,
        runsTestPartTwo: partTwoRT,
        runsTestPartThree:partThreeRT,
        eventLog:event_log,
    });

    //write data to Database
    save_data(jsPsych.data.getLastTrialData());
```

Comment: Don't you need to execute your query too? e.g. `$pdo->execute();`

Comment: I htink that  in $_POST['json']  the key 'json' no exist , try so see with var_dump($_POST) all post values , and get  what you need

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post

Comment: You're just `echoing` a string at the end, not catching any errors then echoing, which is why it's saying it worked. also @Ivanov is right, you need to execute it. Please put this code at the top of your php file and post the error `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Thank you Isaac, I believe that I am executing the query on line 5 of the PHP file, towards the very end of the line, but the error catching was very informative. Here is the error message that I get: `<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: json in <b>D:\home\site\wwwroot\javascript-randomness-project-master\saveData.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in <b>D:\home\site\wwwroot\javascript-randomness-project-master\saveData.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
{'result':'success'}`

Comment: @DanielB That means `$_POST['json']` is not set. Show us where that data is supposed to be sent from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I've edited the post with the code where `save_data()` is called and where the relevant data is stored. Is that what you meant or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: That doesn't show how that post request is sent to your script, are you sure you are sending the information properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There ended up being two problems, one was that my JSON string was not named `'json'` in the `save_data()` function, so the PHP script was throwing an error when I tried using an uninitialized variable since `$_POST['json']` did not exist. The updated and correct function is this one:

```
function save_data(expData){
   data = JSON.stringify(expData)
    $.post('./saveData.php',{json:data},function(response){   //send POST request to PHP file
        console.log("Response: "+response);
    })
}
```

The fix is in line 3, where the input is `{json:data}` instead of simply `data`.

The second problem was that the database itself was misbehaving. One column in particular refused to accept new entries and would throw an error whenever `INSERT` was run. This problem was found by adding a try-catch block to the PHP so that any errors thrown by the database itself were reported. Here are the relevant parts of the updated PHP file:

```
<?php
try{
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$pdo= new PDO( /*irrelevant*/);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

#irrelevant code ---------

}

catch(exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception -> ';
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

That problem was solved by simply deleting the column and adding it again. It was a simple fix but I've included the code to find the problem because I found it useful to be able to see errors thrown by the database itself.

Thank you to everyone who responded for all the help!