# PHP file_get_contents('php://input') results in empty data while doing a post request

Tags: php

File is  running in apache server and when a request was made from postman it showing empty input data below is the code

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "I am here";
$tempval = file_get_contents('php://input');
//$postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo "Data ".$tempval;
```

Output for this file

> I am hereData

which means that tempval is empty i.e no data is recieved from the request

[image: Screen shot of postman request]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - Currently, this question lacks enough information for us to be able to know what your code is actually doing. Please show us all relevant code (and any htaccess file, if you have any).

Comment: Are you printing the data? For example, `echo file_get_contents('php://input');` Just running file_get_contents won't print anything to the screen.

Comment: I tried printing data it isnt giving any output

Comment: @DavidChen In the above code I even tried printing $tempval still it shows empty

Comment: Are you sure you're sending POST or GET data using postman? Can you try `print_r($_REQUEST)`? Also note that you cannot use php://input with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: I am sending it using postman POST request  and data input type is raw data

Comment: @DavidChen  I tried printing print_r(_$REQUEST) it is printing Array ()

Comment: Can you show how you're sending your request with postman? Take a screenshot of your postman.

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8893758/454827

Comment: @DavidChen screenshot sent to your mail please check

Comment: Just a helpful advice. Don't use `echo "I am here";`, etc. Get yourself an IDE with a debugger (such as [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) (there are plenty of others, but that one is pretty much "industry standard"), and learn how to debug. You can set a “breakpoint” on a line and run your code until that line is reached. At that point, you can see the values of variables (and change them), see the “call stack” (which function called the function …. That called the current function, plus their parameters); you can step through your code, line by line, and more.  Make that a habit

Comment: @MuraliKrishnamraju Can you change the data type to `JSON (application/json)`? See this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHEih.png

Comment: @DavidChen  yeah I tried that way as well it still shows a empty request

Comment: Have you made sure you can see any errors that might be reported? See [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: Can't help but notice the URL in your screenshot looks a little odd. Instead of `localhost/postmasterstorelogs.php/`, try `http://localhost/postmasterstorelogs.php`, ie with `http://` prefix and no trailing slash

Comment: Is it possible file_get_contents is disabled, and you don't have warnings/errors enabled? Can you try what Phil suggested and see if any errors show?

Comment: actually the original code is present on remote server i cant change stuff there if something goes wrong everything will be screwed i just tested piece of code locally

Comment: Can you post the output of `phpinfo()` please?