# Submitted POST not read by php://input

Tags: php

I have a simple test form in html responseTest.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="catchResponse.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="test" value="not empty" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I've got a simple catchResponse.php:

```
<?
include('config.php');
$obj=file_get_contents('php://input');
$fp=fopen('response2.txt','w+');
fwrite($fp,print_r($obj));
?>
```

If I run responseTest.html, response2.txt is empty. I'm clearly missing something basic here but cannot find it.

Comment: You will find the values in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, this was doing the trick: enctype='application/json'

Comment: echo $_POST['test'];