# Unable to Receive PayPal IPN Response in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have been at this for 3 days now and still can't get it to work.

What I want to do is to get PayPal response from the IPN listener so that I can modify my database accordingly, but no matter what I do, it just won't work. I have already done the following in my PayPal Sandbox account:

1. Enabled Auto Return
2. Set Auto Return URL ('paypal/success')
3. Enabled Payment Data Transfer (PDT)
4. Enabled IPN message reception
5. Set IPN URL ('paypal/ipn')

The redirect to Auto Return URL works fine and I receive the payment data in success page, but the IPN won't process for reasons beyond me. A quick look at the IPN history on my PayPal profile shows that the messages are being sent, but I don't receive them at my end.

Here is my current IPN listener: **Paypal/ipn**

```
public function ipn() { 
        //Build the data to post back to Paypal
        $postback = 'cmd=_notify-validate'; 
        // go through each of the posted vars and add them to the postback variable
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            $postback .= "&$key=$value";
        }

        // build the header string to post back to PayPal system to validate
        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";//or www.sandbox.paypal.com
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($postback) . "\r\n\r\n";

        // Send to paypal or the sandbox depending on whether you're live or developing
        // comment out one of the following lines
        $fp = fsockopen ('www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);//open the connection
        //$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
        // or use port 443 for an SSL connection
        //$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

        if ( ! $fp ) {
            // HTTP ERROR Failed to connect
            $message = 'HTTP ERROR Failed to connect!'; 
            $this->email_me($message);
        } else { // if we've connected OK

            fputs ($fp, $header . $postback); //post the data back
            while ( ! feof($fp) ) {
                $response = fgets ($fp, 1024);

                if (strcmp (trim($response), "VERIFIED") == 0) { //It's verified

                    //read the payment details and the account holder
                    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
                    $receiver_email = urldecode($_POST['receiver_email']);

                    // further checks
                    if( ($payment_status == 'Completed') && ($receiver_email == $this->business_email) ) {

                        $message = 'IPN verified successfully!';
                        $this->email_me($message);

                        // Insert the transaction data in the database
                        $this->product_model->insert_transaction_details($_POST);

                    } else {

                        $message = 'Payment could not be verified!';
                        $this->email_me($message);  

                    }

                } else {

                    $message = 'IPN invalid!';
                    $this->email_me($message);  

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please? 
Also, is there anyway I can check the IPN response ("VERIFIED" or "INVALID") on chrome debugger or in my PayPal Sandbox dashboard? I can see delivery status in my dashboard but it doesn't say 'Verified' or 'Invalid' anywhere.

Comment: Is your IPN end point accessible from the internet?  If it is on a local host PayPal won't be able to connect to it.

Comment: It's on a live server.

Comment: Is it firewalled?  See https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/what-are-the-ip-addresses-for-sandbox-paypal-servers-ts1157

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean @Mark_1

Comment: If your server is behind a firewall you will need to add a rule to allow PayPal's IPN process to connect to your server.  If your server is already accessible to everyone this won't be required.

Comment: There is an IPN simulator, use that for the testing purpose

Comment: @Mark_1, my server is not behind a firewall.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz, The IPN simulator seems to be faulty, it always returns "Unable to establish handshake" error.

Comment: I just spotted that you are using http 1.0 for your connection, PayPal stopped supporting this a few months ago https://www.paypal.com/uk/smarthelp/article/when-was-http-1.0-support-discontinued-on-www.paypal.com-ts1488 try changing to http 1.1

Comment: Ok Let me try that @Mark_1

Comment: Didn't work @Mark_1

Comment: Must the ipn url be a php page that has the .php extension? Can't it be a funcion? Just asking because most of the tutorials I have seen has the ipn url ending with .php

Comment: Sorry http 1.1 wasn't the solution but I think you will need to use it anyway once you solve the real problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! I wrote the IPN handler inside a controller that allows access to users who are logged in as admin. Apparently, the IPN method was denying access to PayPal to verify the transaction. I figured this out and wrote the IPN method in a different controller and everything worked perfectly.

I also changed my IPN handler to this code (although the original might still work... i didn't try it):

```
class Paypal_ipn extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('product_model');
        $this->sandbox = $this->config->item('sandbox'); 
        $this->paypal_host = $this->config->item('paypal_host'); 
        $this->paypal_url = $this->config->item('paypal_url'); 
        $this->business_email = $this->config->item('business');
    }


    public function ipn() {
        // STEP 1: Read POST data

        // reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
        // issues with array data in POST
        // reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 
        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
        $myPost = array();
        foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
          $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
          if (count($keyval) == 2)
             $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
        }
        // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
           $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
        } 
        foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
           if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
                $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
           } else {
                $value = urlencode($value);
           }
           $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }

        // STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate

        $ch = curl_init($this->paypal_url);

        $headers = array(
            'POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1',
            'Host: ' . $this->paypal_host,
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($req),
            'User-Agent: PayPal-IPN-VerificationScript',
            'Connection: Close'
        );

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
            curl_close($ch);
            exit;
        }
        curl_close($ch);

        // STEP 3: Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            // check whether the payment_status is Completed
            // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
            // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
            // process payment

            // assign posted variables to local variables
            $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
            $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
            $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
            $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
            $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
            $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
            $receiver_email = urldecode($_POST['receiver_email']); 
            $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
            $school_id = $_POST['custom'];

            // further checks
            if($payment_status == 'Completed') {

                $message = 'IPN verified successfully!';
                $this->email_developer($message);

                // Insert the transaction data in the database
                $this->product_model->insert_transaction_details($_POST);

            } else {

                $message = 'Payment could not be verified!';
                $this->email_developer($message);  

            }

        } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
            // log for manual investigation
            $message = 'IPN Invalid!';
            $this->email_developer($message);

        }
    }

}
```

For those that might experience my predicament, ensure you also do the following:

1. If you enabled Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF), ensure the IPN listener/handler is whitelisted, else IPN message will fail (Error 403 in PayPal IPN history).
2. To be sure your IPN listener is working well, run it as a URL and see the response. If there is any error, it won't work. For response, trying echoing "Verified" or "Invalid".
3. Use the [PayPal IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/) to test the process. Include a procedure that will submit information to the database upon success.

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

use php://input instead of $_POST

reson described here in details : [PHP "php://input" vs $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)

also paypal has documentation for implementing IPN Listener and its in php as well
[Paypal tutorial](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/#do-it)