# Converting JavaScript array to PHP using fetch and then sending email

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, localhost, fetch

I'm struggling trying to convert my JavaScript array of emails into a PHP array which I can then send an email back to using my localhost.

I have an input field in my html that is populated by the user (one at a time) which uses .push in JavaScript to put them into the array. I have tried to use fetch to then convert this array into PHP, which I can then then use to send an email back to the email addresses using PHPMailer.

The emails aren't appearing in my console as an array, but will do if I change the content type to "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". However, the emails still aren't being sent this way.

This is only for a small uni project, that's why I am only concerned about sending the emails through my localhost as I won't be hosting the project anywhere.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="names" placeholder="Name" />
<input type="text" id="emails" placeholder="Email address" />
<input type="button" onclick="addTo()" value="Add" />

<input type="button" id="done-button" onclick="completed()" value="Done" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var names = [];
var emails = [];
var allNumbers = [];

function addTo() {
    names.push(document.getElementById("names").value);
    document.getElementById("names").value = "";
    emails.push(document.getElementById("emails").value);
    document.getElementById("emails").value = ""; 
}

function completed() {
    var numbers = names.length;
        for (var i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
            allNumbers.push(i);
        }

    fetch("http://localhost:8888/fetchme.php", {
        method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: "no-cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
        cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: "same-origin", // include, *same-origin, omit
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
        referrer: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *client
        body: emails // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    }).then((response) => {console.log(response)}); // parses response to console
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
var_dump($_POST);

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "example@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->setFrom('example@gmail.com', 'Example');

$emails = json_decode($_POST);

if (isset($emails)) {
    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        $mail->addAddress($email);
        $mail->Subject = 'Your Results';
        //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
        //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
        //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('index.html'), __DIR__);
        $mail->Body = 'Hello, this is my message.';
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo "Message sent!";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `exit` stops anything after it from running.

Comment: If you're posting the data as json in the body, you might need to fetch it using `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');`. You can read more about the difference  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)

Comment: `$emails = json_decode($_POST);` makes no sense. See @MagnusEriksson comment for the usual way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `fetch()` with an array as body doesn't send a JSON string. What's being sent to the server is a comma separated list of the email addresses. Anyway, PHP won't put them into `$_POST` because the body is not a valid query string.

First, you should use `JSON.stringify()` to convert the `emails` array to a JSON string. Then, in PHP, you could read the request body with `http_get_request_body()`.

Or, you can build the query string to set it as the body of the request, and then you'll be able to use `$_POST` normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **class** instead of **id** for name and emails,
then try to get value in javascript itself with console log if you are getting value in javascript before passing it to PHP