# Passing POST parameters to PHP does not work

Tags: php, web, hosting

I am sending parameters to a PHP file as a POST request, direct from my browser like :

`example.com/`
with `example.php?CID=1`

But not getting the values in the PHP file.

I am sending parameters to a PHP file as a POST request, direct from my browser like

in the php file i am trying to read :

```
$cid = $_POST["CID"];
$cname = $_POST["CNAME"];
```

But the local variables are null after executing this.

I also tried doing this :

```
echo var_dump($_POST);
```

and it returns :

```
array(0)
```

i am hosting this on a paid hosting server, and the configuration allows upto 1000 parameters.

Comment: If you are passing parameters in url, use $_GET instead of $_POST

Comment: Thank you Rakesh. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The way you have set this up you are using the get method

```
$cid = $_GET["CID"]; 
$cname = $_GET["CNAME"];
```

If you are wanting to use post then please read the PHP manual
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score -2):

first of all try this [PHP "php://input" vs $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)

php://input

it will solve your issues and let you process developement as workaround - it is very usefull when communicating with pure json not as jason passed into Post field.

next make a check configuration of your server - i had the same problem with nginx and solved it somehow but do not remember how ;)