# Calling method in PHP file from separate JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a javascript file from which I am trying to make a ajax call to execute method of a different php file.

Javascript file - a.js

```
function update() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"abcd.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {"updateMethod()"}

            success:function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
         });
}
```

PHP file - abcd.php

```
<?php

class abcd {
    public function updateMethod() {
        //execute this part of the code
    }

    public function insertMethod() {

    }

    public function deleteMethod() {

    }


}
```

I am not able to make a call to the PHP method. What is wrong with my AJAX query or what do I need to do in PHP file side to call the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you try to do, but you can do it this way:

```
function update() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"abcd.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {methodName: "updateMethod"},
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
     });
}
```

On server side:

```
<?php

class abcd {
    public function updateMethod() {
        //execute this part of the code
    }

    public function insertMethod() {

    }

    public function deleteMethod() {

    }
}

$abcd = new abcd();
$method = $_POST['methodName'];
$result = $abcd->$method();
```

Comment: Not working. Getting error "Undefined index: methodName"

Comment: Print_r($_POST); and see what is there.

Comment: Some other information .. ""parent_id":3,"children":[]}]}]} ".

Comment: This means that you show us wrong or not full code. According to __this__ ajax - `$_POST` should contain only one key.

Comment: Not wrong code. Full code is huge and I am debugging just part of it.

Comment: Ajax request provided in my code sends __just one__ parameter in `$_POST`. What is happening in your __real code__ I don't know.

Comment: I had few other information as well. So I parsed it to get the relevant key from it. It worked then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
dataType: 'json',
```

and send data without json

If you sending json in php must be:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

[PHP "php://input" vs $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)

Or beter jquery:

```
var methodName = "YourMethodName";
var y = "Cymbal";

$.post( "test.php", { methodName: methodName, lastname: y })
  .done(function( data ) {
   alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is more secure and I think you also need function arguments for CRUD actions(Not tested):

backend:

```
class CRUD
{
    public function update($args) 
    {
       $input = $args['exampleInput'];
       // sanitize input 
       // prepared query
       // $stmt->execute($input);
    }
}


function access($class, $method, $args) 
{
    if (method_exists($class, $method)) {
        return call_user_func_array([$class, $method], [$args]);
    } 
}

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
access('CRUD', $data->method, json_decode($data->args));
```

js:

```
function handleAction(methodName, arguments) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "crudFile.php";
    type: "POST",
    data: { method: methodName, args: arguments },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
}

var inputs = {
  exampleInput: function () {
    return document.getElementById('your-div-id').textContent();
  },
};

// usage

handleAction('update', inputs);
```