# Php - How can I recieve a simple post body without setting up routing?

Tags: php, postman

I want to have a PHP script that I post to with Postman. In the body, I have a simple JSON string and I want to read that string in my PHP script. I currently have a local XAMPP 7.3.10 server setup.

So in Postman, I Post to `http://localhost/upload.php` and then in my PHP script, I echo and var_dump the `$Post`. But I get an empty array back in the response?

I'm new to PHP so I'm not really sure if this is the way to do it?

**JSON body**

```
{
    "Test": "testValue"
}
```

**Php**

```
<?php
echo "POST: ";
print_r($_POST);
var_dump($_POST);

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    echo "POST: ";
    print_r($_POST);
    var_dump($_POST);

    echo "FILES: ";
    print_r($_FILES);
    var_dump($_FILES);
} else {
    echo "The post array is empty.";
}
```

**Response in Postman**

```
POST: Array
(
)
array(0) {
}
The post array is empty.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get JSON-string from POST-body you need to use [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php) function:

```php
$json_string = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

However, the `$json_string` contains string after that operation. To convert string JSON to PHP array use [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```php
// the second parameter is for array result, default behavior returns object
$array_data = json_decode($json_string, true);
```

Your approach doesn't work because to populate $_POST array PHP requires POST body to have a specific format, the same as the GET-parameters format:

```
keyName=value&anotherKey=value2
```

Comment: Aah I see after reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post it makes more sense. So is there any disadvantage to post a raw body? Maybe less secure or something?