# Sending data alongside FormData as one Object in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to pass a FormData inside a JSON array to an AJAX script:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    let formData = new FormData(this),
        data = {'action': 'insert', 'data': formData};

    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        url: '/wp-content/plugins/eng-dealer-map/bin/Admin.php',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(res) {console.log(res)},
        error: function(res) {console.log(res)}
    })
});
```

Then /bin/Admin.php

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. $ds. 'wp-content'. $ds. 'plugins'. $ds. 'eng-dealer-map'. $ds. 'vendor'. $ds. 'autoload.php';

    var_dump($_POST);
    $admin = new \App\Endpoint\Admin(['action' => $_POST['action'], 'data' => $_POST['data']]);
    echo $admin->execute();
```

Which, in turn, finally goes to this (minified) class:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Endpoint;

    class Admin
    {
        protected $db;
        protected $table;

        protected $sql;
        protected $data;

        public function __construct($foo)
        {
            require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'wp-config.php';
            global $wpdb;

            $this->db = $wpdb;
            $this->table = '`'. $this->db->prefix .'trey_is_the_best`';

            $this->sql = $this->build($foo['action']);
            $this->data = $foo['data'];
        }

        public function build(string $action)
        {
            switch($action)
            {
                case 'insert': return $this->insertSql(); break;
                case 'update': return $this->updateSql(); break;
                case 'remove': return $this->removeSql(); break;
                default: throw new \Exception('trey'); break;
            }
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            if (!empty($this->sql)) {
                try {
                    if ($this->db->query($this->db->prepare($this->sql, $this->data))) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        throw new \Exception($this->db->last_error);
                    }
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                return 'SQL empty!';
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, it seems `$_POST` gets lost along the way. Adding this in my JS:

```
for (let pair of formData.entries())
{
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]);
}
```

which shows my data correctly. I then `var_dump($_POST)` in `bin/Admin.php` which shows an empty array.

I changed `'data': formData` to `'data': 'hello, world'` so I have a feeling FormData doesn't like being inside a JSON array with other elements?

So how do I send FormData with other elements to my AJAX script? I know I could use:

```
formData.append('action', 'action-value')
```

but that feels like it's an extra step when it could just been sent as one object to my script.

I also tried using `JSON.stringify` on `formData` but again, nothing. Is there a way I can send formData **alongside** other data as one object without using `.append()`? Or is that my only option?

Comment: What's in `file_get_contents('php://input')` ?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte ah interesting.. [object Object]

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post

Comment: Composing `data` like that is a bad idea, but you can get this to work if you use `let data = {'action': 'insert', 'data': $(this).serialize()};`. I'd append the `action` to the formdata instead.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte ahh interesting read! So using the `php://input` I can get `[object Object]` - so how do I parse that? I have a feeling that formData doesn't like being a part of an object, feels like it expects everything to be a part of it rather than it coexisting

Comment: is it a multipart form? If not you can use `data: $(this).serialize() + "&action=insert",`

Comment: @ChrisG may I ask why? (I prefer the PHP side of life to JS haha) I can try the serialize idea though :)

Comment: Not sure what JS vs. PHP has to do with that, it's a bad idea because jQuery can't deal with it. You need to compose a proper POST request, and while my suggestion allows that, it inserts a query string as parameter in a query string, which should send shivers up and down everybody's spine. If you add the `action=insert` to the form data instead, the problem instantly dissolves into neatness.

Comment: @ChrisG because I don't know enough js/jQuery to know what's good and bad haha :p I've opted for `formData.append()` for some reason, it just felt weird that I couldn't append one object to another, but I guess that's the joys of JS dev haha

Comment: Putting the FormData object inside another object is no problem at all, but in order to send it to the server it has to be serialized in some way. JS/jQuery easily supports doing that for you, but it expects either a FormData object or a regular object, not a nested combination of the two. My suggestion turns the form data into a string, so that works fine, but it creates an ugly mess like `action=insert&data=username%30admin` because the form data querystring now becomes a value in the outer querystring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a feeling FormData doesn't like being inside a JSON array with other elements?

Correct. You can't convert FormData to JSON.

> So how do I send FormData with other elements to my AJAX script?

Add the extra data to the FormData.

> I know I could use:
>
> ```
> formData.append('action', 'action-value')
> ```

Yes, do that.

> but that feels like it's an extra step when it could just been sent as one object to my script.

The `FormData` object **is** one object. You just need to add the data to it instead of adding the data to a different object and then trying to add the data from `FormData` to it.