# Woocommerce webhook is not working on localhost

Tags: woocommerce, webhooks

```
$post_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$id = (int) filter_var( $post_data->id, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
```

I don't know whats wrong. In `var_dump($post_data)` the `$post_data` is always `string(0)`.

Comment: So simple `$id = (int) $_POST['id']` isn't enough?

Comment: @emix - apparently, [there is a good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post) for using `php://input`.

Comment: @emix That doesn't work either

Comment: Could you give more info on what you are trying to do? Are you trying to get Woocommerce to send a webhook request to a server you have running locally?