# sending xml file through XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, xml, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to send **XML** file via **XmlHttpRequest** but unfortunately nothing is sent,
when I print **$_POST**
it gives me an **empty array**.
I tried two ways to create XML

1. createDocument
2. XMLstring then parseFromString  to xml.

but to no avail.

I think the reason is the header:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

because when I replace it with this header

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

it works  but it sends string not xml file
I know that I can send xml string to my php then parse it to xml file but I don't want this way, I need to send xml file directly

even if i changed header to text/xml and used *in php*

```
$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo gettype ($rawData);
```

it returns string so 
I have to use simplexml_load_string to convert it to object
this is my js code:

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost/dashboard/webservice/SOAP/soapServer/ex.php");
var xmlDoc;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.response;
    console.log(xmlDoc);          
    }
};
//xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

//way1
var xmlString = "<?xml version='1.0'?><root><query><author>John Steinbeck</author></query></root>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

//way2
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
var peopleElem = doc.createElement("people");
var personElem1 = doc.createElement("person");
personElem1.setAttribute("first-name", "eric");
personElem1.setAttribute("middle-initial", "h");
personElem1.setAttribute("last-name", "jung");
  
xmlhttp.send(xmlDoc);
```

php code ,so simple:

```
?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000");
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP "php://input" vs $\_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)

Comment: thnx for helping... I am afraid not, I can use text/xml header with file_get_contents but it still the same problem it returns string when i print gettype()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can use text/xml header with file_get_contents

That is the correct approach.

> but it still the same problem it returns string when i print gettype() –

PHP will automatically parse a request with a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` body or a `multipart/form-data` body and populate `$_POST` with the data.

Those are the **only** content-types it has any automatic handling for. It has no features for automatically parsing an XML body. You have to do it explicitly (by reading the body from STDIN and then passing the resulting string through [an XML library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)).