# Ajax PHP placing variables in string for API call

Tags: php, ajax

I have read and attempted to implement all solutions I found on the web but until now I can't get this to work, so time to ask for help:

I send the following Ajax call to my PHP file:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "libs/php/geolocate.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                lat: $lat,
                lon: $lon
            },
```

this invokes the following call in the php file:

```
$result = $geocoder->geocode( '51.952659, 7.632473' );
```

Everything works okay, but what I'd like to do next is replace the preformatted coords, with those that I send across in the ajax call.
This is where I am failing, I have tried varying methods to inject lat and lon including logic from a prior project: `$_REQUEST['lat']`, nothing seems to work.

Can someone please advise what format I need to use?

many thanks

EDIT var_dump() output:

````
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\wamp64\www\geonamesExample\libs\php\geolocate.php:2:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>{"results":[{"source":"opencage","formatted":"Friedrich-Ebert-Straße 7, 48153 Münster, Germany","geometry":{"lat":51.9526599,"lng":7.632473},"countryCode":"DE","timezone":"Europe\/Berlin","roadinfo":{"sideOfRoad":"right","speed":"km\/h"},"currency":{"name":"Euro","symbol":"€"}}]}```
````

Comment: Please run `var_dump($_REQUEST)` in the receiving PHP script and add the output to the question.

Comment: thanks for replying, jack solved the issue below, but appreciate the guidance on bug finding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$_POST['lat']` and `$_POST['lon']`

```
$result = $geocoder->geocode( $_POST['lat'] . ', ' . $_POST['lon']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually php passes automatically variables with the header

application/x-www-form-urlencoded

To retrieve the values with your current setup you need to capture the data using

php://input

I.e

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input') ;

var_dump($data); // associative array with your variables
```

More info here

[PHP "php://input" vs $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post)

Comment: `you need to capture the data using php://input` No, he doesn't.