# js fetch post works, but php is empty

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

I have this fetch method

```
loginbutton.onclick = (e)=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    var creds = {
        login: login.value,
        pass: pass.value
    }
    
    fetch('functions/asklogin.php', {
        method: "POST",
        header: {"Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"},
        body: JSON.stringify(creds)
    })
    .then(resp => resp.text())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

When I click, my xhr body is well fed:

[image]

But, if I try to echo these parameters from my asklogin.php

```
echo "no".$_POST['pass'].":".$_POST['login'];
```

All I get is `no:`

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the result when you `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: This should help you out - https://stackoverflow.com/q/8893574/4287624

Comment: @UrmatZhenaliev empty array

Comment: @Richard .. in short, for `$_POST` to work you need to send the data as form data along with a respective content-type. If you send json data then you need to use `php://input` to read the posted data.

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have mentioned that I am aware that the stream is feed (but I thought it was explicit since I've post a screenshot of it). Thanks anyway
@HymnZzy yes, but how do you pass data as a classic form within fetch api? I can't find the right syntax in the api doc

Comment: `body: Object.entries(creds).map(([k,v])=>{return k+'='+v}).join('&')` and set content-type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: You can do as HymnZzy said but it's probably simpler (and less brittle) just to change the way PHP reads the data.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`$_POST` in PHP will recognize the only the form data (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`) with a specified content type header.

For any other content type, you'll need to use `php://input` to read and parse the data.

For your case, changing the data you send through `fetch` should solve the issue.

```
...
fetch('functions/asklogin.php', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"},
    body: Object.entries(creds).map(([k,v])=>{return k+'='+v}).join('&') // in jQuery simply use $.param(creds) instead
})
...
```

An alternative solution will be changing how the PHP side reads data

```
...
if( is_empty($_POST) ){ $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true) }
...
```

Comment: Ok, the php side adaptation is working. Not the fetch approach, it seems to be missing something in the string? anyway thanks!

Comment: This should be:
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)