# Python requests allows urlencode but not json

Tags: python, php, json, python-requests

I have a test environment of two Linux machines - one with with a PHP script, the other with a python script. I am trying to send an array of dictionaries as a JSON to the PHP script using the python. At this point, the PHP script does nothing but print what it received:

```
// Contents of set-data.php
<?php print_r ($_POST); ?>
```

The python script is as follows:

```
# Contents of test.py
import requests
import json

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
url = "http://mylocation/api/set-data.php"
payload = {'data': '[{"1": "Test_1", "2": "test_2"}]'}
   
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

No matter how I run this in my test environment, the response is empty

```
// Result from set-data.php
Array
(
)
```

I have tried to change the `data` field in the request to `json`, tried to set the payload to a `json.dumps` object, and various other techniques, but nothing seems to work. However, if I send this information as a urlencoded form from the python script, it works.

```
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
payload='data=%5B%7B%221%22%3A%20%22Test_1%22%2C%20%222%22%3A%20%22test_2%22%7D%5D'
```

I know that the machine running the PHP script is accepting the JSON because when I do this from my location machine using Postman the result is correct.

```
// Result from set-data.php sending from local machine
Array
(
    [data] => [{"1": "Test_1", "2": "test_2"}]
)
```

Does anyone know why? I think something may be misconfigured on the python machine, but what?

Comment: Try with `print_r(file_get_contents("php://input"));` instead of `$_POST`;

Comment: @FelippeDuarte that does prove that the data is getting there - the data does print. But why does that happen?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post

Comment: Ah. But do you know why it works using Postman, but not in the Linux environment?

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's postman or python script. The HTTP protocol expects some Content-Type header and PHP will use it to populate $_POST or php://input