# How do I get the correct php array format for WordPress Ajax $_POST data?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm implementing ajax within WordPress for the first time but running into a block here and I can't figure out the issue. Any help is appreciated.

So I'm basically trying to pass data to an ajax callback within WordPress.

JS :

```
    window.utils.http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: ajaxurl + '?action=ajax_submit',
      json: true,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data: {
        test: 'testing123',
        quiz_results: {
          'a': 1,
          'b': 4,
          'c': 2
        }
      },
      onload: (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
    })
```

Note: I get the same issue even with jQuery's ajax function

Functions.php :

```
    function ajax_submit() {
        print_r($_POST);

        wp_die();
    }

    add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_submit', 'ajax_submit');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_submit', 'ajax_submit');
```

My JS console log response :

```
Array
(
    [{"test":"testing123","quiz_results":{"a":0,"b":0,"c":0}}] => 
)
```

As you can see, the php array isn't formatted correctly, I'm unable to select values too. If I `echo $_POST['test']` or `echo $_POST[0]->['test']` I get nothing.

Thanks

Comment: can you tell us what is the output of this `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime you can't access data through the superglobal `$_POST`.
In your case modify your `ajax_submit` function like this

```
function ajax_submit() {
    // reading raw data from request body
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode($data, true);
    
    wp_send_json( $data, 200);
    wp_die();
}
```

for more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8893792/9554058) answer

Answer (score 0):

Try `wp_send_json()`

```
function ajax_submit() {
    print_r($_POST);
    wp_send_json( $_POST );
    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_submit', 'ajax_submit');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_submit', 'ajax_submit');
```

Comment: thanks but not sure that works here it gives me : {"{\"test\":\"testing123\",\"quiz_results\":{\"a\":0,\"b\":0,\"c\":0}}":""} 

I need the data on the php side, not the JS side (that's mainly for testing the response)

Comment: can you tell us what is the output of this print_r($_POST);

Comment: It's just strange to me that echo $_POST['test'] doesn't work here, when everywhere online says it should.

Comment: Output for print_r($_POST) is : 

Array
(
    [{"test":"testing123","quiz_results":{"a":0,"b":0,"c":0}}] => 
)

Comment: try to print echo ` "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";` and post output this in your question.

Comment: <pre>Array
(
    [{"test":"testing123","quiz_results":{"a":0,"b":0,"c":0}}] => 
)
</pre>