# html inuput field data send with jquery to PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

```
$(".save_form_email").on('click', function() {
    var pocet = $('#save__cena').val();
  console.table(pocet);
  $.ajax({
    url: '/modules/mod_custom_extended/tmpl/default.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      pocet: pocet
    },
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    success: function(response) {
      console.table(response);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log('AJAX request failed: ' + textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
    }
  });

});
```

This is the PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['pocet'])) {
  $temp_pocet = $_POST['pocet'];
}
?>
```

This is my attempt to send value of html input field with id "save__cena" to the php so i can later use this price to send it to stripe.
Currently i have nothing in php variable temp_pocet

Comment: _"Currently i have nothing in php variable temp_pocet"_ - where and how exactly have you verified that?

Answer (score 0):

When you send JSON data using an ajax request to php, the data is not accessible in the `$_POST` superglobal. You need to read from `php://input` instead like so:

```php
<?php
$form_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

$_POST only works with data that has the `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`, not `application/json`.

Additional info: [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8893792/14569480)

EDIT

If you also plan on returning a json response from the php script, then you should move the code that processes the ajax request to a separate php file that is not mixed with any html code. This is to prevent html characters from being sent along with the json response and causing it to become corrupted.

Oh and you should also change your content-type header to `application/json`

Comment: but his contentType is set to that: `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',` shouldn't it work then?

Comment: No, if you wish to send json data, the content type header should be set to the appropriate value, which is `application/json`. You're confusing the server by saying you're sending one type of data and then sending a completely different type.

Comment: im confused, you answer me with form data but i need to send just one atribute and that is $('#save__cena').val(); to the PHP. Could you share example for this ?

Comment: @PeterB your code is working fine. if you want that value to be seen in console use 
if (isset($_POST['pocet'])) 
{
    $temp_pocet = $_POST['pocet'];
    return $temp_pocet;
}

Comment: no its not working, its empty in php.

Comment: @PeterB post your html code

Comment: its rly big form i would rather not. But this is the part which is needed <input id="save__cena" type="hidden" name="cena" value="2 400">
i need this value in php before whole form submit. 
@Snm

Comment: wait, you only need that value in your php before submiting the form?

Comment: yes, and also after but this is okey and working. 
i need it before to use it in php and send it to the stripe as init amount.

Comment: but if you do `$(".save_form_email").on('click', function() {` that means you pressed `the submit` button of the entire form. Shouldn't you do something like a `onblur` or `onchange` on that field then send the data via ajax? since you want to send just 1 value

Comment: this is something else .save_form_email is only some random button inside of form not sa submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Debug with alerts.

```
$(".save_form_email").on('click', function() {
        var pocet = $('#save__cena').val();
      alert("Step 1");
      console.table(pocet);
      $.ajax({
        url: '/modules/mod_custom_extended/tmpl/default.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          // I change this line
          // pocet: pocet -> Original
          "pocet": pocet // updated
        },
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(response) {
          alert("Step 2");
          console.table(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert("Step 3");
          console.log('AJAX request failed: ' + textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
        }
      });
    
    });
```

PHP DEBUG

```
<?php
 echo "<script>alert('PHP Step 1');</script>";
if (isset($_POST['pocet'])) {
  echo "<script>alert('PHP Step 2');</script>";
  $temp_pocet = $_POST['pocet'];
}
?>
```

This is an error detection system through alert, tell me what alerts you get

Comment: Hello, thank you for code. But it looks like i have same result. 
console.table(response) is empty. 
I dont understand this since i did a lot of those requests in past. 
Im working in Joomla module maybe if it help as additional information. 
also this js is in same file as url (/modules/mod_custom_extended/tmpl/default.php) ajax request, maybe this is problem since there is also other parts PHP there.

Comment: I have implemented a basic error detection system, try it and tell me